# unable to use PHP 5.5 to add data to MySQL 5.7 in webmatrix 3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, webmatrix, webmatrix-3

Please help, this is driving me mad! I have, I thought, a simple registration form that I am trying to send data with PHP to MySQL in Webmatrix. (PHP 5.5 to add data to MySQL 5.7 in webmatrix 3) however, I get the following error in Chrome:

**The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
500**

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';

$db_name = 'MySQL10';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$fname = $_POST('fname')
$lname = $_POST('lname')
$email = $_POST('email')

//Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli ( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

//Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_1 (fname_1, lname_1, email_1)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email')";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Here's Mark up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test Page</title>

    </head>

<body>

<div class="registration">
  <form name="test" method="post" action="demo.php" autocomplete="on">      
      <p>First name:<input type="text" name="fname" value=""></p>
      <p>Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" value=""></p>
      <p>Email Address:<input type="email" name="email" value=""></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>         
</div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A 500 error is VERY general.  Check your server's error logs.

Comment: When you see a 500 server error, you have to look in your Apache error log to see what happen. In above code, you have to add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of `$fname = $_POST('fname')`  and following two lines.

Comment: @fusion3k Semicolons will help but `$_POST` is an array so the proper syntax would be `$_POST['fname']`

Comment: thank you all. I added the `[]` and the `;` and having checked the input using: `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}` i was kindly reminded that I had not set a default value for the ID in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all. I added the [] and the ; and having checked the input using: if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "New record created successfully"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "
" . $conn->error; } i was kindly reminded that I had not set a default value for the ID in the database!